# Handle 200Mb response size in rest api

Tags: spring-boot, rest, streaming, spring-webflux

We have an API which connects to oracle database to pull data, max response size for the request is 200mb and record count is 80k. As we have to create 80k objects for each request  I'm  getting out of memory some cases.
What could be the best solution to handle responses , I'm thinking of streaming , webflux. Which could be the best solution here?

I have tried streaming

Comment: You should add more details to your question. What's the media type of the request and the response? Can you give a small sample of request and responses? Can you share a simplified code snippet of what you currently have in your app?

Comment: This question is quite abstract. It would be easier to give some advices seeeing some general fragments of your code. Basically WebFlux exactly can be used for such tasks